# using jquery mousemove and setTimeout and clearTimeout to reveal/hide a menu

Tags: jquery

I pasted some code below of what seems to be a common approach to reveal a menu on mousemove. It seems that as the mouse continues to move, the duration of the timeout increases. What's up with that? Is there a reason why the cleartimeout would not be working?

```
var timer;
    $(document).mousemove(function() {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = 0;
        }

        $('.navi a, a.left, a.right').animate({top:'0px'},'fast');
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
           $('.navi a, a.left, a.right').animate({top:'50px'},'fast');
        }, 1000)
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is, you're starting the animation to move up over and over again on each mousemove event. due to jquery's animation queuing, every call to `animate()` on the same object will get queued, so your your final `animate()` call in the delayed function (moving the element down again) has to wait until all 'up' animations are done.

see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeFVT/1/) for a quick fix

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the great explanation and the working example. Makes perfect sense...and works beautifully.